# Asynchronous Mongoose Calls

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, mongoose, async.js

I've got a `match` function that pairs or partial-pairs two exchange bets together. At first I wrote a neat function but it was synchronous (using for loops) and now I'm having trouble translating it into asynchronous code using nested callbacks and the `async` package. I'll paste below my synchronous and asynchronous function so far. At the moment, I get errors in the async code because `Cannot read property '_id' of undefined` but `_id` gets pulled from the query stored in `results`.

**Async Function**

```
match : function(){
    var results = Bet.find({"paired" : false}, {_id:1, bet:1, market:1, odds:1, student:1, to_match:1, stake:1})
    .sort({createdAt : 1});
    async.forEach(results, function(doc, callback){
        var result = doc[0];
        var id = result._id;
        var stake = result.stake;
        var odds = result.odds;
        var market = result.market;
        var student = result.student;
        var side = result.bet;
        var to_match = result.to_match;
        var opp_results = Bet.find({"student":student, "market":market, "paired":false, "settled":false, 
            "bet": {$ne : side}, "_id" : {$ne : id}});
        async.forEach(opp_results, function(opp_doc, callback2){
            var temp_to_match = to_match;
            var array = opp_doc[0];
            var opp_id = array._id;
            console.log("Comparing " + id + " with " + opp_id);
            var opp_paired = array.paired;
            var opp_to_match = array.to_match;
            var opp_settled = array.settled;
            if(temp_to_match <= opp_to_match){
                temp_to_match -= opp_to_match;
                opp_to_match -= temp_to_match;
                if(temp_to_match <= 0){
                    paired = true;

                }
                if(opp_to_match <= 0){
                    opp_paired = true;
                }
            }
        }, callback);
    }, function(err){
        console.log("done");
    });
}
```

**Sync Function**

```
sync_match : function(){
    Bet.find({"paired" : false}, {_id:1, bet:1, market:1, odds:1, student:1, to_match:1, stake:1})
    .sort({createdAt : 1})
        .then(function(doc){
            for(var j = 0; j < doc.length; j++){
            var result = doc[j];
            var id = result._id;
            var stake = result.stake;
            var odds = result.odds;
            var market = result.market;
            var student = result.student;
            var side = result.bet;
            var to_match = result.to_match;
            Bet.find({"student":student, "market":market, "paired":false, "settled":false, 
                "bet": {$ne : side}, "_id" : {$ne : id}}).then(function(results){
                for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                    var temp_to_match = to_match;
                    var array = results[i];
                    var opp_id = array._id;
                    console.log("Comparing " + id + " with " + opp_id);
                    var opp_paired = array.paired;
                    var opp_to_match = array.to_match;
                    var opp_settled = array.settled;
                    if(temp_to_match <= opp_to_match){
                        temp_to_match -= opp_to_match;
                        opp_to_match -= temp_to_match;
                        if(temp_to_match <= 0){
                            paired = true;

                        }
                        if(opp_to_match <= 0){
                            opp_paired = true;
                        }
                    console.log("we made it this far);
                    }
                }

            });

    }});
}
```

Comment: Bet.find is asynchronous so you can't use it like this `var results = Bet.find(...)` the easiest you can do is to add `exec` -> `Bet.find(...).sort(...).exec(function(err, results){  async.forEach(results, ...)});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Update: This solution has a slight bug. For some reason when one field gets paired, it should stop, however it keeps pairing and pairing..)

From Molda's suggestion I managed to get a working asynchronous solution:

```
match : function(){
    Bet.find({"paired" : false}, {_id:1, bet:1, market:1, odds:1, student:1, to_match:1, stake:1})
    .sort({createdAt : 1}).exec(function(err, results){
    async.forEach(results, function(doc, callback){
        var id = doc._id;
        var stake = doc.stake;
        var odds = doc.odds;
        var market = doc.market;
        var student = doc.student;
        var side = doc.bet;
        var to_match = doc.to_match;
        Bet.find({"student":student, "market":market, "paired":false, "settled":false, 
        "bet": {$ne : side}, "_id" : {$ne : id}}).exec(function(errs, res){
        async.forEach(res, function(opp_doc, callback2){
            var temp_to_match = to_match;
            var opp_id = opp_doc._id;
            var opp_student = opp_doc.student;
            var opp_paired = opp_doc.paired;
            var opp_to_match = opp_doc.to_match;
            var opp_settled = opp_doc.settled;
            if(temp_to_match <= opp_to_match){
                var update_to_match = temp_to_match - opp_to_match;
                var update_opp_to_match = opp_to_match - temp_to_match
                if(update_to_match <= 0){
                    paired = true;
                    update_to_match = 0;

                }
                if(update_opp_to_match <= 0){
                    opp_paired = true;
                    update_opp_to_match = 0;
                }
                Bet.update({"_id" : id}, 
                    {$set : {'to_match': update_to_match,'paired' : paired}}
                    ,{new : true, multi: true}).exec(function(err){
                        if(err)
                            throw err;
                    });
                Bet.update({"_id" : opp_id}, 
                    {$set : {'to_match': update_opp_to_match, 'paired' : opp_paired}}
                    ,{new : true, multi:true}).exec(function(err){
                        if(err)
                            throw err;
                    });
            }
        }, function(err){
            if(err){
                throw err;
            }
            callback();
        })});
    }, function(err){
        console.log("done");
    })});
}
```